# Xcode 9+iphone8+Fabric can't use beta to install testing app

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9, google-fabric, iphone-8

I keep got this error message on iPhone8:

> "The developer needs to upload a build that supports your device's architecture (armv6)."

And the same version is ok to install on other devices (iphone7,6,ipad...).

So far I had tried

- update mac to 10.12.6 and reboot
- keep clean whole Xcode project
- update crashlytics/fabric version
- try Xcode 8.3 and 9GM

And nothing work for me.

[image: error message on iPhone8 safari]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a known issue that the team is working to fix. I'll post an update to this answer once we have it working. It's top priority for us and we're looking to have a solution out ASAP.

UPDATE:

This is fixed now. Beta installs work on iPhone 8.

Comment: Similar thing seems to happen on new iPad Air 3; it's detecting armv7 on it. Is someone working on fix for it on fabric side?

Comment: Thanks for the report. This is fixed now. Can you let me know if you're still hitting the error?

Comment: Great! Thanks for letting us know. Glad you're all set.